# How do I add a custom attribute type?

Tags: product-attribute, custom-attributes

I would like to create a custom attribute type in Magento 1.9.  This is obviously possible as the WEEE part of Magento Core does it.

I've found the following information about it, but neither of them are comprehensive enough:

1. ["Custom Catalog Input Type for Store Owner" question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699226/custom-catalog-input-type-for-store-owner-for-magento-product-attributes)
2. Inchoo's [Adding Magento Attribute with Custom Input Renderer](http://inchoo.net/magento/adding-magento-attribute-with-custom-input-renderer/).

2 isn't worthwhile as it doesn't give you a way to do this for attributes that have not been created yet.  1 is close but provides no additional information so it doesn't give me much to work off of nor does it tell me how it works.

So, How would you add a custom attribute type?

**I will be awarding a 100 point bounty (2/3 of what I have) to a comprehensive answer**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the custom attribute? Your question currently is too broad, as customizing an attribute could be very extensive (not suitable for Q&A).

Comment: Please edit your question and add more context. I think there is a better way to fix your problem

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt I discovered this problem while doing a job, but I don't think the generic is too broad.  You can create custom input types that have a different backend/frontend renderer for custom attributes.

I do still need to take a look at source_model as that may be the piece that was missing from the links above.

Answer (score 1):

Custom attributes are possible in Magento. The extent of customization can vary, and I have not seem one tutorial that covers everything, understandably. You'll need to be specific. What kind of customization are needed?

Whatever you want to achieve, the first place to start is to create a custom source model so that the source of data for your attribute is custom. Take a look at `source_model` column in `eav_attribute`, you'll see different models being loaded. From there, you'll need to make sure and modify the attribute indexing processes, etc.. Look up how Magento does it with its own source models.

I recommend Googling "magento custom source model" and going from there.